# Serializing Objects That were sent via SOAP

Tags: c#, serialization, soap, dynamics-crm

I'm dealing with some SOAP requests/response to Microsoft CRM, that I'm attempting to save off.  The Response object I'm attempting to Serialize is the `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata.OptionSetMetadataBase` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.optionsetmetadata.aspx).  When I attempt to serialize my object using this extension method:

```cs
public static string Serialize(this IExtensibleDataObject obj, bool indent = false)
{
  NetDataContractSerializer contractSerializer = new NetDataContractSerializer();
  using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter((IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
  {
    using (XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter((TextWriter) stringWriter))
    {
      if (indent)
      {
        xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xmlTextWriter.Indentation = 2;
      }
      contractSerializer.WriteObject((XmlWriter) xmlTextWriter, (object) obj);
      return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233088
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata.OptionMetadataCollection' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types."
    Source: "System.Runtime.Serialization"
    StackTrace: "at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type)
        at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.ThrowTypeNotSerializable(Type type)
        at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.GetValidContract(SerializationMode mode)
        at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.GetDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle)
        at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.GetDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle)
        at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
        at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
        at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
        at WriteOptionSetMetadataToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )            
        at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
        at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContract contract, Hashtable surrogateDataContracts)
        at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)
        at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
        at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph)
        at DLaB.Common.Extensions.Serialize(IExtensibleDataObject obj, Boolean indent)"
    TargetSite: {Void ThrowInvalidDataContractException(System.String, System.Type)}
```

I would assume this is possible since I just retrieved this information via a SOAP request, and therefore it was just deserialized.  Here is the Soap Response if it helps:

```xml
<ExecuteResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services">
    <ExecuteResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <b:ResponseName>RetrieveAllOptionSets</b:ResponseName>
        <b:Results xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
            <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <c:key>OptionSetMetadata</c:key>
                <c:value i:type="d:ArrayOfOptionSetMetadataBase" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Metadata">
                    <d:OptionSetMetadataBase i:type="d:OptionSetMetadata">
                        <d:MetadataId>0872a2b1-6db1-48a9-8aa2-1686f294b1e0</d:MetadataId>
                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                        <d:Description>
                            <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                    <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                    <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                    <b:Label>Need type</b:Label>
                                    <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                </b:LocalizedLabel>
                            </b:LocalizedLabels>
                            <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                <b:Label>Need type</b:Label>
                                <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                            </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                        </d:Description>
                        <d:DisplayName>
                            <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                    <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                    <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                    <b:Label>Need</b:Label>
                                    <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                </b:LocalizedLabel>
                            </b:LocalizedLabels>
                            <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                <b:Label>Need</b:Label>
                                <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                            </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                        </d:DisplayName>
                        <d:IsCustomOptionSet>false</d:IsCustomOptionSet>
                        <d:IsCustomizable>
                            <b:CanBeChanged>false</b:CanBeChanged>
                            <b:ManagedPropertyLogicalName>iscustomizable</b:ManagedPropertyLogicalName>
                            <b:Value>true</b:Value>
                        </d:IsCustomizable>
                        <d:IsGlobal>true</d:IsGlobal>
                        <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                        <d:Name>need</d:Name>
                        <d:OptionSetType>Picklist</d:OptionSetType>
                        <d:IntroducedVersion>5.0.0.0</d:IntroducedVersion>
                        <d:Options>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>Must have</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>Must have</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>0</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>Should have</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>Should have</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>1</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>Good to have</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>Good to have</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>2</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>No need</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>No need</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>3</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                        </d:Options>
                    </d:OptionSetMetadataBase>
                    <d:OptionSetMetadataBase i:type="d:OptionSetMetadata">
                        <d:MetadataId>3041d03c-4166-4814-a2d4-1e3d93caf2f1</d:MetadataId>
                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                        <d:Description>
                            <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                    <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                    <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                    <b:Label>Categories for connection roles.</b:Label>
                                    <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                </b:LocalizedLabel>
                            </b:LocalizedLabels>
                            <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                <b:Label>Categories for connection roles.</b:Label>
                                <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                            </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                        </d:Description>
                        <d:DisplayName>
                            <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                    <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                    <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                    <b:Label>Category</b:Label>
                                    <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                </b:LocalizedLabel>
                            </b:LocalizedLabels>
                            <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                <b:Label>Category</b:Label>
                                <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                            </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                        </d:DisplayName>
                        <d:IsCustomOptionSet>false</d:IsCustomOptionSet>
                        <d:IsCustomizable>
                            <b:CanBeChanged>false</b:CanBeChanged>
                            <b:ManagedPropertyLogicalName>iscustomizable</b:ManagedPropertyLogicalName>
                            <b:Value>true</b:Value>
                        </d:IsCustomizable>
                        <d:IsGlobal>true</d:IsGlobal>
                        <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                        <d:Name>connectionrole_category</d:Name>
                        <d:OptionSetType>Picklist</d:OptionSetType>
                        <d:IntroducedVersion>5.0.0.0</d:IntroducedVersion>
                        <d:Options>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>Business</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>Business</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>1</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>Family</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>Family</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>2</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>Social</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>Social</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>3</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>Sales</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>Sales</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>4</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>Other</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>Other</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>5</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>Stakeholder</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>Stakeholder</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>1000</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>Sales Team</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>Sales Team</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>1001</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>Service</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>Service</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>1002</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                        </d:Options>
                    </d:OptionSetMetadataBase>
                    <d:OptionSetMetadataBase i:type="d:OptionSetMetadata">
                        <d:MetadataId>8e76ca1c-8d7c-45d2-b870-25b108a31792</d:MetadataId>
                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                        <d:Description>
                            <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                    <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                    <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                    <b:Label>If there has been initial communication with this lead.</b:Label>
                                    <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                </b:LocalizedLabel>
                            </b:LocalizedLabels>
                            <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                <b:Label>If there has been initial communication with this lead.</b:Label>
                                <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                            </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                        </d:Description>
                        <d:DisplayName>
                            <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                    <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                    <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                    <b:Label>Initial Communication</b:Label>
                                    <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                </b:LocalizedLabel>
                            </b:LocalizedLabels>
                            <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                <b:Label>Initial Communication</b:Label>
                                <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                            </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                        </d:DisplayName>
                        <d:IsCustomOptionSet>false</d:IsCustomOptionSet>
                        <d:IsCustomizable>
                            <b:CanBeChanged>false</b:CanBeChanged>
                            <b:ManagedPropertyLogicalName>iscustomizable</b:ManagedPropertyLogicalName>
                            <b:Value>true</b:Value>
                        </d:IsCustomizable>
                        <d:IsGlobal>true</d:IsGlobal>
                        <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                        <d:Name>initialcommunication</d:Name>
                        <d:OptionSetType>Picklist</d:OptionSetType>
                        <d:IntroducedVersion>5.0.0.0</d:IntroducedVersion>
                        <d:Options>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>Contacted</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>Contacted</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>0</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                            <d:OptionMetadata>
                                <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Color i:nil="true"/>
                                <d:Description>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels/>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel i:nil="true"/>
                                </d:Description>
                                <d:IsManaged>true</d:IsManaged>
                                <d:Label>
                                    <b:LocalizedLabels>
                                        <b:LocalizedLabel>
                                            <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                            <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                            <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                            <b:Label>Not Contacted</b:Label>
                                            <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                        </b:LocalizedLabel>
                                    </b:LocalizedLabels>
                                    <b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                        <d:MetadataId i:nil="true"/>
                                        <d:HasChanged i:nil="true"/>
                                        <b:IsManaged>true</b:IsManaged>
                                        <b:Label>Not Contacted</b:Label>
                                        <b:LanguageCode>1033</b:LanguageCode>
                                    </b:UserLocalizedLabel>
                                </d:Label>
                                <d:Value>1</d:Value>
                            </d:OptionMetadata>
                        </d:Options>
                    </d:OptionSetMetadataBase>
                </c:value>
            </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        </b:Results>
    </ExecuteResult>
</ExecuteResponse>
```

How do I get around this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DataContractSerializer` instead - it will do the job. It can serialize types not marked with `[DataContract]` or `[Serializable]` attributes (default constructor is required + only public members will be serialized):

```
public static string Serialize(this IExtensibleDataObject obj, bool indent = false)
    {
        DataContractSerializer contractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            using (XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
            {
                if (indent)
                {
                    xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    xmlTextWriter.Indentation = 2;
                }
                contractSerializer.WriteObject(xmlTextWriter, obj);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That was it.  Awesome. Why or how should you use one vs the other?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rjacobs/2010/04/15/datacontractserializer-vs-netdatacontractserializer/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890693/netdatacontractserializer-vs-datacontractserializer)